# Bitbucket unable to push commit with Jira key

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira

We have two instance of Jira as A and B and both are setup with OAuth(impersonation) in the Bitbucket application link where A is set as Primary.

We have a push check hook enabled in the bitbucket repo and correctly setup. When we are trying to push the changes with valid issue key of Jira B, hook is getting declined whereas while pushing the changes in Jira A,push is working fine

While checking we have concluded that Jira A is setup as Primary thus allowing to push the changes with valid Jira key .

My question is why changes are not getting pushed to Jira B. if we make B as primary then able to push else not.

Would it be possible to make both Jira A and B set as primary or both take push requests and process the commits made.

Looking forward for a response.

Comment: What protocol are u using? http? https? ssh?

Comment: @CodeWizard While pushing the changes, We are using `ssh`